# Miniforge Conda "PackagesNotFoundError" on ARM processor for PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, conda, nvidia-jetson, mini-forge

I am unable to install any packages with miniforge 3 (conda 4.11.0).

I am attempting this on a Jetson Nano Developer Kit running Jetpack. Initially it had conda installed but it seems to have gone missing, so I decided to reinstall conda. It looks like the base version of anaconda/miniconda is having issues running on ARM processors, and so I downloaded miniforge which apparently is working.

I have set up an environment successfully, but attempting to download pytorch gives the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-aarch64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/abinit/linux-aarch64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/abinit/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/matsci/linux-aarch64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/matsci/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-aarch64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

This is for Python 3.7.12. It seems this issue persists no matter what version of pytorch I try to install.

I am however able to install some other packages, as I was able to install beautifulsoup4.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `linux-aarch64` version of pytorch on the default conda channel, see [here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pytorch)

This is of course package specific. E.g. there is a `linux-aarch64` version of `beautifulsoup4` which is why you wre able to install it without an issue.

You can try to install from a different channel that claims to provide a pytorch for aarch64, e.g.

```
conda install -c kumatea pytorch
```

Comment: This is the answer. I should note that installing it this way does not give pytorch access to CUDA, which I need. Building PyTorch from a `.whl` file  or source seems to be the only solution here.